# How to set write permission to a single file in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have an MVC app and I need to set write permission to `Everyone` on a single file.
The file is generated on the fly during installation by a custom action script. The file itself is created inside the app folder.

I know the final path of the file, after the installation process

Online I've seen only examples for setting permission to folders and subfolders, none of them seemed to address my issue

Comment: If you are using a script to create the file, why not to give the permission as well?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky I could do it, yes